# Check the file name in the upload folder before uploading the file

Tags: php

I am use the following code:

```
if(file_exists("upload/" . '1.txt')
....
```

This code checks only the file with the name of "1" and ".txt" in the upload folder There is or not. I want to check it for any file named "1" with any extension (for example 1.jpg, 1.png, ...). What is the simplest code that comes to your mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = glob ("upload/1.*");
```

and see whether $result contains anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match("/^1\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/",$filename)){}
```

Comment: This checks the file name. The asker is looking for if the file exists.